# Links in nonalphabetic order

Tags: links

On wordpress.barrycarter.info, the links sidebar is in alphabetical 
order by category ("My ... Stuff"), which looks weird for "My other 
stuff". How can I order the link categories myself?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the plugin [My Link Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-link-order/) does exactly that.

> My Link Order allows you to set the order in which links and link categories will appear in the sidebar. Uses a drag and drop interface for ordering. Adds a widget with additional options for easy installation on widgetized themes.

Answer (score 0):

This is in a widget? Or coded into the sidebar?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_bookmarks

is the code for showing your blogroll links, with orderby parameters.

If you are particular about the order of categories, and category_orderby isn't cutting it, you can use wp_list_bookmarks numerous times, each time showing only one category

If you are using the widget,maybe look for a different plugin with widget, or consider hardcoding this?

Comment: The filter `'widget_categories_args'` lets you modify the arguments for `wp_list_categories()` when it's used in the default widget.

Comment: @Voodoo Yes, this is the standard "blogroll" widget. Is there a cleaner way of doing this w/o editing the code? Like a wp_list_bookmarks widget or something? Or can I add an extra field to links called 'order'?

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong widget. The filter for bookmarks is `'widget_links_args'`.